# Php from android in json not posting to table, is there something wrong in my code?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have an android app converting info into JSON and sending it to php/MySQL, get response back on the phone just fine but nothing is getting into the table, I'm not that experienced in php, did I screw up this code?

```
<?php
include('../htconfig/dbConfig.php'); 
$dbSuccess = false;
    $dbConnected = mysql_connect($db['hostname'],$db['username'],$db['password']);

    if ($dbConnected) {     
        $dbSelected = mysql_select_db($db['database'],$dbConnected);
        if ($dbSelected) {
            $dbSuccess = true;
        }   
    }
$data_back = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));


$userName = $data_back->{"User"};
$password = $data_back->{"Pword"};
$PurchasedFrom = $data_back->{"Pfrom"};
$VIN = $data_back->{"VIN"};
$Color = $data_back->{"Color"};
$MakeIndex = $data_back->{"Make"};
$ModelIndex= $data_back->{"Model"};
$Year = $data_back->{"Year"};
$Bid = $data_back->{"Bid"};
$INV = $data_back->{"PurchasePrice"};
$BidContact = $data_back->{"Contact"};
$BidEmail= $data_back->{"Email"};


mysql_query("Insert Into tblinventory (VIN, MakeIndex, ModelIndex, Year, Color,Bid,INV, 
BidContact, BidEmail, PurchasedFrom)
VALUES ('$VIN','$MakeIndex', '$ModelIndex', '$Year', '$Color', '$Bid', 
'$INV', '$BidContact', '$BidEmail', '$PurchasedFrom')");

$responses = array();
 {
    $responses[] = array( $VIN . " " . $MakeIndex . " " . $ModelIndex." ". $Year." " );
}


header("Content-type: application/json");


echo json_encode($responses);
?>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. This, assuming you are using `mysql_` as DB connection. If it is anything other than that, those APIs do not intermix.

Comment: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Your code is dangerously vulnerable.

Comment: How do you call mysql_connect()? Try to use mysql_error() to see error message if any.

Comment: after adding or die (mysql_error()); it throws "no database selected", but I have the database in include('../htconfig/dbConfig.php'); and have returned a success connection every time before adding the mysql query.  I'll be reading PHP The Right Way and the other links, but for now I just want to post the information to the table, I'll fix the code up after I've proven it working.

Comment: The first step would be to write the query manually and see if it runs at all. The second step is to re-write that as code. I'd **strongly** recommend picking a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that fits your style and needs and use the database layer provided rather than slamming around with low-level SQL if you're having trouble here. It's 2014. You don't need to write SQL all the time for everything any more.

Comment: Show us what you've got in `dbConfig.php` and replacing actual credentials with `xxx`, save us from guessing till the question gets closed because of too many comments.

Comment: Ok, simple errors, I forgot to add the connection code for the database, and a few names in the table are wrong like Pfrom instead of PurchasedFrom.  Got it working now...Thanks for the pointers on error_reporting and the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to add error checking code and make sure there is an actual database connection.  Also make sure your input and query have the same name..see PurchasedFrom and Pfrom.  Thanks for the help guys and thanks for the links, they will help a lot.  Happy Coding :)